# OpenGL - Directional bright Light?

Tags: object, opengl, 3d, lighting

The Light, I added, looks on objects weak? I want it brighter and I don't want to give the Light position. I mean, I want a bright Light on all the screen with same brightness in the middle or at the corners?

```
float[] lightColor = {1, 1, 1, 0};
float[] lightPosition = {0, 0, 10, 0};  

@Override
public void render () {

    ...
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
    ...
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPosition, 0);
}
```

Comment: Your light is already directional at an infinite distance, since w in {0, 0, 10, 0} is set to zero (the last element in this 4-tuple). And it points in +z direction ({0, 0, 10} vector).

Comment: So.. what should I change? What add?

Comment: How can I know :) May be your camera is not positioned correctly and so you see unlit part of an object. Or may be you did not specify your object's material parameters to be used for lightning (see glMaterial and glColorMaterial). Check also normal vectors for object's vertices.

Comment: There's no way to know without seeing how you set up the object's material.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is an ambient light, not a directional one.